Filtering by time zone in postgres sql using EF Core
I'm developing an app using ASP.NET Core 8 and EF Core 8.
I have installed the package Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL Version=8.0.2.
I have a scenario where I need to filter an entity by date by applying a timezone. The date is in UTC. I have used the EF.Functions.AtTimezone method in to convert time in SQL Server when working with EF Core. I tried to get the same/similar approach with Postgres and EF Core, but it seems like there is no built-in method for that in Postgres with EF Core.
I googled and came up with this where it's functioning as expected in Postgres SQL with EF Core.
public async Task<(IReadOnlyList<AdminEventSummaryDto>, int)> GetEventListForDay(Paginator paginator, string timezoneName, DateTime date, Guid userId)
{
    var dateString = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

    var sqlQuery = $@"
    SELECT * 
    FROM ""SN_ATS_Event""
    WHERE (""EventStartDateTimeUtc"" AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE '{timezoneName}')::date = '{dateString}'::date";

    var query = _context.Events
        .FromSqlRaw(sqlQuery)
        .Where(w => w.InterViewers.Any(a => a.InterviewerId == userId));

    var totalRecordCount = await query.CountAsync();

    var list = await query.Select(e => new AdminEventSummaryDto()
    {
        // select what ever is needed

    })
    .Skip((paginator.PageNumber - 1) * paginator.PageSize)
    .Take(paginator.PageSize)
    .AsSplitQuery()
    .ToListAsync();

    return (list, totalRecordCount);
}

My problem is is this correct or is there a better way that I can apply the timezone I want without having to write a raw SQL statement?

TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(utcDateTime, timezone) - Date and time functions

this answer works with timestamp with timezone, in my scenario, the time is utc, but the type is timestamp without timezone, so whem i apply TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(utcDateTime, timezone) it throws an error saying TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId is only supported on columns with type 'timestamp with time zone. is there any work around?
